# Two men and four women line up at a checkout counter in a store

Tags: probability, probability-theory, education

Two men and four women line up at a checkout counter in a store.

$a)$ In how many ways can they line up?

$b)$ In how many ways can they line up if the first person line is a woman, and then the line changes by gender $(w, m, w, w, m, w)$?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Write mathematical expressions or numbers between dollar symbol $.

Comment: In how many ways can they line up if the first person line is a woman, and then the line changes by gender (w, m, w, w, m, w)?   i want to know to know the solution of this question

Comment: You have to show your primary effort. what you have tried ?

Comment: 4 choices for the first position, then 2 for the second, then...

Comment: i have tried but i cant solve it

Comment: @AliIqrar, just write  what you have tried. No matter right or wrong

Comment: i have solved the part a of question and the answer is 720 but not able to solve part b

Answer (score 2):

a) it is $6! = 720$ as you mentioned

b) If the order is $(w, m, w, w, m, w)$, you can permute women and men in $4!$ and $2!$ ways so number of arrangements $= 4! \times 2! = 48$